# Trying to submit form values where only part of the form binds to a model (with ASP.Net MVC3)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I apologize in advance for a wall of text below. I hope to provide all the info at once that may be needed to understand what I'm doing.

I've got a page where I'm collecting some basic user info (name, email, etc). In another portion of the page I have a multiple choice quiz form (using radio inputs for each question). My goal is to collect the contact info, process the quiz answers, and store a score with the contact info in a QuizResults table.

This may be a case of over thinking, or over engineering.. so feel free to tell me I'm going about this all wrong.

Here's my Quiz related models:

```
public class QuizType {

    public QuizType() {
        this.QuizQuestions = new HashSet<QuizQuestion>();
        this.QuizResults = new HashSet<QuizResult>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<QuizQuestion> QuizQuestions { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<QuizResult> QuizResults { get; set; }
}

public class QuizQuestion {

    public QuizQuestion() {
        this.QuizAnswers = new HashSet<QuizAnswer>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public int QuizTypeId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<QuizAnswer> QuizAnswers { get; set; }
    public virtual QuizType QuizType { get; set; }
}

public class QuizResult {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string TesterName { get; set; }
    public string TesterEmail { get; set; }
    public string TesterCompany { get; set; }
    public string TesterPhone { get; set; }
    public string ApproverName { get; set; }
    public string ApproverEmail { get; set; }
    public bool HasCompanyIssuedIdBadge { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }

    public virtual QuizType QuizType { get; set; }
}

public class QuizAnswer {

    public QuizAnswer() {
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool isCorrectAnswer { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set; }
    public int QuizQuestionId { get; set; }

    public virtual QuizQuestion QuizQuestion { get; set; }
}
```

So basically I can create a Quiz Type, then for each type I can create multiple questions, each question can have multiple answers. I'm not trying to post back any data for QuizType, QuizQuestion, or QuizAnswer. Those are just there to help build my page[s].

This is where I start scratching my head. I need to be able to iterate through QuizQuestions and QuizAnswers to create the multiple choice form. But I also need to bind part of that form to QuizResults for posting back....  here's what I've got now in order to display the form (but not work correctly).

First, I've created a ViewModel:

```
public class QuizViewModel {
    public IQueryable<QuizQuestion> QuizQuestions { get; set; }
    public QuizResult QuizResults { get; set; }
}
```

Then in my controller:

```
    public ViewResult Index() {

        var questions = 
            from q in unitOfWork.QuizQuestionRepository.Get() 
            where q.QuizType.Name.Equals("QuizTypeOne")
            select q;

        var qvm = new QuizViewModel { 
            QuizQuestions = questions
        };

        return View(qvm);
    }
```

I won't post my entire razor view, but I think these are the pertinent parts:

```
@model QuizViewModel

@* *** MISC STYLE, JS, ETC LEFT OUT FOR BREVITY *** *@

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.QuizResults.TesterName)<br />
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.QuizResults.TesterName)

    @* *** OTHER FORM FIELDS LEFT OUT FOR BREVITY *** *@

    foreach (var item in Model.QuizQuestions) {
        <div class="wizard-step">
            <h3>@item.Question</h3>
            @{
                // I've been tinkering with this trying to find a way to get it
                // so that the input would have the right id to be picked up and
                // dropped into my post object correctly
                var inputId = "SelectedAnsers[" + item.Id + "]";
            }
            @foreach (var answer in item.QuizAnswers) {
                <input type="radio" id="@inputId" name="@inputId" value="@answer.Id" /> @answer.Answer @:(@answer.isCorrectAnswer)
                <br />
            }
        </div>
    }

}
```

Back in my controller I have a method setup to handle the post, but it's not doing anything at the moment. I'm just running in debug and looking at the values posted when I submit the form.

```
[HttpPost]
public ViewResult DukeDrive(QuizViewModel quizViewModel) {
    // I have a breakpoint set so that I can inspect quizViewModel
    return View();
}
```

In my head I want to be able to process the quiz form values, calculate the score, then create a new QuizResult object based on the contact info filled out and the newly calc'd score. I'll be darned if I can find the right way to do it though.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add another parameter of type [`FormCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.web.mvc.formcollection%28VS.98%29.aspx) which contains all posted values.

```
[HttpPost]
public ViewResult DukeDrive(QuizViewModel quizViewModel, FormCollection formData) {
    // I have a breakpoint set so that I can inspect quizViewModel
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize both would pass through! I'll give that a shot real fast.

Comment: Yep, that gets me where I need to be... of course it's that simple.  Thanks!